# AES key generation for already encrypted data

Tags: encryption, aes

I have a text file named data.txt
I used AES 256key encryption to encrypt it with a password "pass"
The encrypted file name is ency.txt.

Can I generate the password "pass" only from the data.txt and ency.txt?

Thank you for any help. :)

Comment: No; [Compute the AES-encryption key given the plaintext and its ciphertext?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5355/compute-the-aes-encryption-key-given-the-plaintext-and-its-ciphertext)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about security or cryptography and doesn't include a programming problem.

Comment: Note that AES only uses **keys**, not passwords. If passwords are used (possibly using some kind of padding for 4 character passwords), then a brute force attack may be used. It then depends on the randomness of the password if you can find it. "pass" would be pretty easy to find, and since you know the plaintext, you can simply compare the results to see if your password was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you're asking if we can recover the password using a [known plaintext attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack#Present_day)?

The answer is no, as that would completely defeat the purpose of a modern encryption system. In fact, you can see with the link I provided that AES is explicitly stated as an example of a system that is not known to be susceptible to any known plaintext attacks.